# Automation of parsing email body and storing important variables?

Tags: php, email, automation

I have made a php program to eliminate some tedious data entry work at my job. Currently, the way it works is we receive workorder emails, then someone working in the office opens the emails and copies and pastes the info from the body of the email into a form I made. Then I use php to process the data and pick out all the important stuff and put them into variables.

I would like to be able to automate the process even more so the person at the office doesnt even have to copy&paste email data.

Is there a way to automate checking for mail and parsing the email body for variables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help in your situation, but there is a simple PHP email parser.

https://github.com/plancake/official-library-php-email-parser

It will allow you to retrieve the email from the spool, and then parse the email parts out.  From there you could wright some simple code to get the parts of the body you need.

And this could be setup using a simple cronjob that runs every 5 minuets or so.

If the email is not currently being sent to a linux host you can set this up on, you could have a copy of the emails forwarded to the machine you set the script up on.